# Cleaning up the node edit URL

Tags: 7, path-aliases

Say I have node/111/edit, and that node's path is my-node. I want the edit page to be at
my-node/edit, instead of node/nid/edit.

Is there an existing solution for cleaning up the node edit URL, e.g. a custom module or the Pathauto module? All I see for the Pathauto module is a place for page patterns, but that would only handle page views, not edits.

Comment: how about adding an alias with 'URL Alias' ?

Answer (score 7):

This issue in pathauto [Replacing node/XXX/edit](http://drupal.org/node/203804) to mypage/edit lead to this module: [Sub-path URL Aliases](http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias) give it a shot.

> The Drupal Path module matches only full URLs when creating SEO-friendly aliases. This module extends that behavior by also matching known sub-paths and replacing them with their respective alias. For example, if node/1 is aliased to content/alias, this module rewrites the link to the node edit page node/1/edit to use the aliased URL content/alias/edit instead. This also includes Views URLs taking a node as argument (node/%/yourview), in short, every URL that is based on, or extends, an existing alias. In combination with the Pathauto module it is possible to get rid of all remaining exposed internal URLs.